# how to make a spaciel line in css?

Tags: css, geometry

i try to make that in css
http://prntscr.com/l19jl9

but i only sucsses to 
http://prntscr.com/l19juk
https://prnt.sc/l19itx

this my code:

```
    .halfCircleLeft{
     height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     background:green;
     }
```

how i can do that?

Comment: Please use the image icon to upload images to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Make height and weight same. And increase height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly the shape that you have in your image, but it's simple and it's likely close enough:

```css
#box {
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px / 50% 0% 0% 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

The above solution uses elliptical border-radius, which is specified using a slash (/).

---

Another approach here is much closer to your original image, but it takes significantly more code to implement, and it's quite a bit more brittle too to customise:

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow:  hidden;
  width: 200px;
}

#box::before {
  position:  relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: -75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -10;
}

#box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box">
   <div id="content">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach uses an oversized circle, which is then clipped by a `#wrapper` div using `overflow: hidden;`. The `#content` div isn't strictly necessary for the shape, but it may make it easier to position something inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow: hidden` to the container and make the inner div a big circle, it will give you the effect you want.

```css
.cont{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.round-back{
  top: -100px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="round-back"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: תודה רבה, עזרת לי מאוד